# Prove two cylinders of different radius are not isometric

Tags: differential-geometry

First i provide the definition i have of locally isometric

[Definition of locally isometric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCKhI.jpg)

I want to proove two cylinders with different radius are not isometric. A teacher at my college suggested i try to proove they are not locally isometric which would proove they are no isometric.

So i go ahead and compute the first fundamnetal form

Suppose i have two cylinders given by

$\phi(u,v) = (r_1 cos(u),r_1sin(u),v)$

$\psi(u,v) = (r_2 cos(u),r_2sin(u),v)$

Now

$E = <\phi_u,\phi_u> = r_1^2 \\ F <\phi_u,\phi_v> = 0 \\ G = <\phi_v,\phi_v> = 1$

Doing the same with $\psi$ i get:

$\hat{E} = r_2^2 \\ \hat{F} = 0 \\ \hat{G} = 1$

Now, I was lead to believe since $E \neq \hat{E}$ then given surfaces cannot be locally isometric.

But i dont see how this is true.

First, the E's (coordinates of the first fundamental forma) ive calulated are based on two parametrizations, changing the parametrization could change the E's to a case where they match.

And assuming this is not the case, and i could never change parametrizations so that $E,F,G,...$ coincide, I still dont see why different E's makes it impossible to have.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150042/discussion-on-question-by-el-zar-prove-two-cylinders-of-different-radius-are-not); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution
Suppose both cylinders($C_1$ and $C_2$) with different radii where isometric. That is we have an isometry $F$ between them

Given the Egregium Gauss theorem we know that $F$ preserves geodesics.
More so we know that $F$ preserves closed geodesics.
Now the only closed geodesics on the cylinder are the circles (in spanish called parallels).

So any circle on $C_1$ is a closed circle on $C_2$ via $F$.

But we also now , since F is an isometry, that it preserves distances (eg norm). So both of this circles should have the same length, which is absurd because both of them have different radii. Therefore two cylinders of different radii can't be isometric

Comment: But they *are* locally isometric.